# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java

I  recive a date in this format

```
2014-12-09 02:18:38
```

which i need to convert it to

```
09-12-2014 02:18:38
```

I tried converting this way

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        String input = "2014-12-09 02:18:38";
        String strDate = sdf.format(input);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

But i am getting this exception during Runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:301)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at TestDate.main(TestDate.java:15)
```

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this .

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion). Also, you should be able to solve trivial issues such as this one by yourself by reading the documentation and googling for a few minutes. SO is not a code-writing service and you shouldn't use it for every little question you have; please do some research on your own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String input = "2014-12-09 02:18:38";
    Date date = sdfIn.parse(input);

    System.out.println(sdfOut.format(date));
}
```

Also, note that `m` is for minutes, while `M` is for months.

Comment: @PreethiJain This is a solution but I still strongly recommend to read the docs so you'll understand what you are doing

Comment: The output i am getitng is 29-12-2014 02:18:38 , why 29 is coming in place of 09 ?

Comment: @PreethiJain I have corrected my answer, `yyyy` should be used instead of `YYYY`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
String strDate = sdf.format(input);
```

use

```
String strDate = sdf.parse(input);
```

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Thanks , it returns me Sun Dec 30 02:18:38 IST 8
 How can i get 09-12-2014 02:18:38

Comment: @PreethiJain Read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) carefully and note the difference between `m` and `M`. In fact - look at your pattern in general, it has the years and day the wrong way around.

Comment: If you look at the question I linked there's an extensive explenation, also read the docs on the subject (they can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

    // String to Date:
    String input = "2014-12-09 02:18:38";
    Date date = sdf.parse(input);

    // Date to String:
    String strDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat in can be used to format a Date object.

First you have to parse your string to a Data object using format on the SimpleDateFormat you declared.
After that you can output it using a second SimpleDataFromat to a string you want.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String input = "2014-12-09 02:18:38";
    Date dt = sdf.parse(input);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");        
    String strDate = sdf2.format(dt);
    System.out.println(strDate);
```